# BING MAP LAYER AND PINS : HOW TO DRAW PINS UP ON POLYGON LAYER?

Tags: php, bing, bing-api, bing-maps

i having two var as,

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {
        showMapTypeSelector:false,
        showScalebar:false,
        enableSearchLogo:false,
        showDashboard:true,
        credentials:"Aku0L3I-4aBqUL0zUWpJYNIp-vppMK2h",
        mapTypeId:Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road, 
        zoom:4,
        center:new Microsoft.Maps.Location(38.3466110000000029,-77.0653559999999942)
    });
```

this Map var used to draw polygon on my bing map.

```
greenLayer = new ClusteredEntityCollection(map, {
        singlePinCallback: createPin,
        clusteredPinCallback: createClusteredPin,
        clusterPlacementType: 2,
        clusteringEnabled: true,
        visible: true,
        gridSize: 50

    });
```

this greenlayer is used to draw pins on bing map.

while running,

```
the polygon is up and the pins is down.

i need to draw polygon down and pins up.
```

how to do `greenlayer which comes up` in the bing map.

Comment: sensible title in lower or proper case please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the z-index of ClusteredEntityCollection (as it's supposedly an extension on EntityCollection) with a simple:

```
greenLayer.setOptions({zIndex: 1000});
```